# RtmpLite and NetStream.bufferTime

Tags: flash, rtmp, buffering

Are there any known issues with the [rtmplite](http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/) server and NetStream.bufferTime? For some reason, while adding `NetStream.bufferTime = 2` it doesn't work for me. It does work with Red5 though.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? If you add NetStream.bufferTime = 2 then rtmplite hangs? I also have troubles with rtmplite as well, if I specify cam.setQuality(0,90); then the .flv recording hangs at 2.7MB, without any error messages. (with red5, the same flex code works well...)